# Reducing DNS lookup time

Tags: dns, nameservers

I can see a lot of waiting time and DNS lookup time when hitting my website through Firebug. My website : `http://www.javaexperience.com`

Where as a website like `http://javapapers.com` has a waiting time of 0ms and very less DNS lookup time.

Is there something I can do from website or web host side to reduce this delay? Is there any recommendation for name servers.

Comment: At the risk of coming across as facetious, maybe their DNS server responds faster to queries than yours. Upgrade your DNS server?

Comment: You mean Domain name provider like godaddy, namecheap or the web host to whose name servers the domain is pointing to?

Comment: I mean perhaps `ns1.javaexperience.com` and `ns2.javaexperience.com` (your DNS servers) are just plain slower at answering queries than `ns1.mediatemple.net` and `ns2.mediatemple.net` (their DNS servers). This could be due to many different reasons - the latency from you to each of the servers, caching anywhere along the path, network load anywhere alone the path, random chance...